# How to set TMP dir for JProfiler (offline/remote mode) on Linux/WebSphere

Tags: linux, jvm, websphere, jprofiler

I'm struggling in getting a JVM heap dump by JProfiler set in off-line mode.
By default it will try to save it into tmp folder which in my and perhaps most of the cases, is not big enough.
I then followed the answer from [Jprofiler Remote profiling on linux. How to change path of profiler data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781835/jprofiler-remote-profiling-on-linux-how-to-change-path-of-profiler-data-files)
but the JVM property java.io.tmpdir didn't work

```
JProfiler> Could not seek tmp file. Aborting. Please check your TMP and TMPDIR environment variables.
```

I don't want to change these variables for all processes/users on the servers.

Any clues on how to enforce the JVM prop or change these variables for WebSphere 8.5.5 JVM process started from Dmgr?

JProfiler 8.0.1

Linux Redhat

Answer (score 2):

You have to update to 8.1 (that is covered with the same license), then you can set the VM parameter

```
-Djprofiler.tmpdir=...
```

for the profiled JVM to tell the JProfiler agent to use a different temporary directory.